# Why this Custom Input file is not working in Edge?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Hell, I am building a customized input file, it's working on Chrome, FF, Safari, but not on Edge, any idea?

Here's my demo. Please open it on Chrome then on Edge to understand the issue:

```css
/* /////////////////Custom Upload input///////////// */

.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.custom-file-input::-ms-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-appearance: none;
}

.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'Attach';
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c6c6c6;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, FontAwesome;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}

.custom-file-input:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);
}
```

```html
<input class="custom-file-input" type="file">
```

Comment: Hello, I think the issue is related with `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);`IE doesn't understand backgrounds with gradient. What more problems do you have?

Comment: hi hiad, I have to removed the gradient, but still the same-  the problem is that on Edige it is showing its default input file instead. Run the page on edge to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `::-ms-browse` to style the file input button in Edge. Then we must wrap input type file with label and do something in CSS. And if you want to change the default file input box in Edge, you need to hide it first using `input[type="file"] { opacity: 0;}` and combine js code to show the file name. You could check my sample of styling input type file in Edge and Chrome below:

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e) {
    $in = $(this);
    $in.next().html($in.val());  
});
```

```css
.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-ms-browse  {
  display:none;
}

input[type="file"] {
    display: input-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'Attach';
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c6c6c6;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif, FontAwesome;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}

.custom-file-input:active::before {
  background: linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="custom-file-input">
  <input type="file">
  <span class="fileName">Choose file...</span>
</label>
```